# Get the topmost orchestration ID in Azure Functions app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure functions application runtime version 4.28.4.4, targeting .NET 6.0. A HTTP trigger starts an orchestration with many sub-orchestrations, one from another one. At the end of the chain I have an activity function. In this functions I should be able to get the ID of topmost orchestration started by HTTP trigger. Obviously I'm looking for a way to achieve the goal without passing the ID through all functions explicitly. Any suggestion?

**Update**

A code example to show what I mean:

```
[FunctionName("Test")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{

    var id = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(TestMainOrchestrator),
        "id-i-am-looking-for"); // This ID I will need later
    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, id);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(TestMainOrchestrator))]
public async Task TestMainOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger]IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorA), null);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorA))]
public async Task TestSubOrchestratorA([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorB), null);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorB))]
public async Task TestSubOrchestratorB([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorC), null);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorC))]
public async Task TestSubOrchestratorC([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(TestActivity), null);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(TestActivity))]
public async Task TestActivity([ActivityTrigger]IDurableActivityContext context, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
{
    log.LogWarning("This is activity in orchestration '{0}'", context.InstanceId);
    // Here I should be able to get ID of topmost orchestration.
    // In this particular case it is "id-i-am-looking-for" but it
    // could also be auto-generated so I cannot have it as a constant.
    // "context.InstanceId" contains ID of "TestSubOrchestratorC" and
    // that is all :(
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Comment: please share you function code

Comment: please share what have you tried and what error you are getting?

Comment: Are you using `in Process ` or `isolated` and which version you are using?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya I use the in-process model with runtime version 4.28.4.4

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There is no direct way to get the `instance id` of topmost orchestration without passing the value.

I was able to get the value by creating a `Global variable` and passing the value to it and called it in task activity.

I used your test code and made some changes:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function
    {
        public class OrchestratorIdService
        {
            private static string _topmostOrchestrationId;

            public static string TopmostOrchestrationId
            {
                get => _topmostOrchestrationId;
                set => _topmostOrchestrationId = value;
            }
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(TestMainOrchestrator))]
        public async Task TestMainOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorA), null);
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorA))]
        public async Task TestSubOrchestratorA([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorB), null);
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorB))]
        public async Task TestSubOrchestratorB([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorC), null);
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(TestSubOrchestratorC))]
        public async Task TestSubOrchestratorC([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(TestActivity), null);
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(TestActivity))]
        public async Task TestActivity([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
        {
            log.LogInformation("This is activity in orchestration '{0}'", context.InstanceId);
            log.LogWarning("Main orchestration id id:{} ", OrchestratorIdService.TopmostOrchestrationId);
            // Here I should be able to get ID of topmost orchestration.
            // In this particular case it is "id-i-am-looking-for" but it
            // could also be auto-generated so I cannot have it as a constant.
            // "context.InstanceId" contains ID of "TestSubOrchestratorC" and
            // that is all :(
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }



        [FunctionName("Function_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(TestMainOrchestrator), null);

            log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            OrchestratorIdService.TopmostOrchestrationId = instanceId;
            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```bash
Functions:

        Function_HttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7212/api/Function_HttpStart

        TestActivity: activityTrigger

        TestMainOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

        TestSubOrchestratorA: orchestrationTrigger

        TestSubOrchestratorB: orchestrationTrigger

        TestSubOrchestratorC: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-27T03:26:51.426Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-02-27T03:26:54.533Z] Executing 'Function_HttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d8a95df3-458a-4538-a1ac-9ef4e8568a99)
[2024-02-27T03:26:54.981Z] Started orchestration with ID = '9aef5402821045f3a21eeaf1cbd93cb5'.
[2024-02-27T03:27:02.662Z] Executed 'Function_HttpStart' (Succeeded, Id=d8a95df3-458a-4538-a1ac-9ef4e8568a99, Duration=8260ms)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.072Z] Executing 'TestMainOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=db4b99a6-2cb5-454b-a003-0b9c4b5f9676)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.219Z] Executed 'TestMainOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=db4b99a6-2cb5-454b-a003-0b9c4b5f9676, Duration=172ms)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.371Z] Executing 'TestSubOrchestratorA' (Reason='(null)', Id=252cf8ef-f86f-4747-9d92-6218e989519a)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.379Z] Executed 'TestSubOrchestratorA' (Succeeded, Id=252cf8ef-f86f-4747-9d92-6218e989519a, Duration=8ms)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.466Z] Executing 'TestSubOrchestratorB' (Reason='(null)', Id=655e1361-a13b-4ea6-bea6-93e296d3f5ce)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.476Z] Executed 'TestSubOrchestratorB' (Succeeded, Id=655e1361-a13b-4ea6-bea6-93e296d3f5ce, Duration=9ms)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.557Z] Executing 'TestSubOrchestratorC' (Reason='(null)', Id=8758a7da-8327-450e-be18-356f3f86b1f3)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.660Z] Executed 'TestSubOrchestratorC' (Succeeded, Id=8758a7da-8327-450e-be18-356f3f86b1f3, Duration=102ms)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.793Z] Executing 'TestActivity' (Reason='(null)', Id=682df24d-1651-4e69-ad0e-5a76b1fd2d78)
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.806Z] This is activity in orchestration 'f14f434ef1994f6684d35b7377b01c55:0'
[2024-02-27T03:27:03.815Z] Main orchestration id id:9aef5402821045f3a21eeaf1cbd93cb5
[2024-02-27T03:27:22.656Z] Executed 'TestActivity' (Succeeded, Id=682df24d-1651-4e69-ad0e-5a76b1fd2d78, Duration=18871ms)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution looks weak. Is there any warranty that the HTTP trigger will be executed on the same instance as the activity at the end? Remember that the application will be scaled across multiple instances in production environment.

Comment: Http trigger is starting a orchestration instance an its id value is being saved to the variable. It will always have the topmostorchestrion's id. Your query was to  get the id value.

Comment: In real life, Functions application works on many machines. Each function can be executed on a random instance. Is not it true? So HTTP trigger could start on instance A, the first orchestration on instance B and activity on instance D. Under this circumstances, shared variables make no sense.

Comment: @Infarch Yes, Functions may run on many machines. AFAIK, based on your query this is the only possible way to get the id without passing the value. There is an option of `parentInstanceId` but is returns the parent of the orchestration. for example `TestSubOrchestratorC` will return `TestSubOrchestratorB` Id.

Comment: Well, I think we can close this question. It looks like my problem cannot be solved without passing the ID as an argument.